# perl regex to match multiline with space and non-word characters

Tags: regex, perl

want to check if copyright is exactly as specified:

```
my $copyright_RE= '\s*[^\w]*\s*'."\QCopyright (c) \E".'(\d.*)'."\Q by Bill Shakespeare.\E".'\s*[^\w]*\s*\n*'.
             '\s*[^\w]*\s*'."\QAll Rights Reserved.\E".'\s*[^\w]*\s*\n*'.
             '\s*[^\w]*\s*'."\QGraw Hill publishers, Inc.\E".'\s*[^\w]*\s*\n*';

my $file_head=`head -n 100 /tmp/sample.txt`;
if ($file_head !~ /$copyright_RE/i) {
       print "\nInvalid copyright, or copyright missing\n";

} else {
       print "\ncopyright is good\n";
}
```

This works, but is there a better way to specify "$copyright_RE" and pattern match?

sample.txt has:

```
# Copyright (c) 2008,2009-2011 by Bill Shakespeare. # 
$     All rights reserved.                          $
*     Graw Hill publishers, Inc.                    *
```

Comment: How did you make out on this buddy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could pre-compile with `qr//` and the *x* option.

```
$copyright_RE = qr/
     \s* [^\w]* \s* 
     \QCopyright (c) \E
     ( \d .* )                     # (1)
     \Q by Bill Shakespeare.\E
     \s* [^\w]* \s* \n* 
     \s* [^\w]* \s* 
     \QAll Rights Reserved.\E
     \s* [^\w]* \s* \n* 
     \s* [^\w]* \s* 
     \QGraw Hill publishers, Inc.\E
     \s* [^\w]* \s* \n* 
/xi;
```

However, this regex is frought with backtracking problems on a non-match.

It's better to *limit* the backtracking catastrophy potential.
I've tried to do it with the below change.

Notice the *atomic* group as well `(?>)`

Also, note that `[^\w]` also matches whitespaces `\s` as well.
Might as well get rid of all the `\s` in the regex while your at it.

```
 use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;

my $copyright_RE = qr/
(?>
      [^\w]*  
      \QCopyright (c) \E
      ( \d .* )                     # (1)
      \Q by Bill Shakespeare.\E
      [^\w]*  
      \QAll Rights Reserved.\E
      [^\w]*  
      \QGraw Hill publishers, Inc.\E
      [^\w]*  
 )
/xi;


my $file_head = <DATA>;

print $file_head, "\n";

if ($file_head !~ /$copyright_RE/ ) {
       print "\nInvalid copyright, or copyright missing\n";
} else {
       print "\ncopyright is good ($1)\n";
}    

__DATA__
# Copyright (c) 2008,2009-2011 by Bill Shakespeare. # 
$     All rights reserved.                          $
*     Graw Hill publishers, Inc.                    *
```

Try it out.